# how to turn a whole list into a string and a string back to a whole list

Tags: python, string, list

hello i want to turn a list into string but the whole list

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

and i want it into

```
b = '[1,2,3]'
```

i also want it back from there so i get from

```
b = '[1,2,3]'
```

to

```
c = [1,2,3]
```

so i can use it as normal list again 
i need to convert it this way because i have a list that json got a probleme with and so i want it into a string and then when i need the list out of the json file i want it back as a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List to string is easy enough:

```
>>> str([1,2,3])
'[1,2,3]'
```

Or, as per John Gordon,

```
>>> json.dumps([1,2,3])
'[1,2,3]'
```

And you can convert back using json.loads:

```
>>> json.loads('[1,2,3]')
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: You can even use `json.dumps()` instead of `str()` so the conversions are nicely symmetrical.

Comment: +1 to @JohnGordon 's suggestion. Trying to `json.loads` a list of strings dumped with `str()` will fail due to differences in quoting styles.