# got a problem with kivy and json i want to put some widget info in my json file but json does not accept the list i put in it

Tags: python, json, kivy

Hello im working on a game and i want to save some data interms the game crashes but json dont accepts this the list looks like this:

```
[<game.Bullet object at 0x0000026AACF37C88>, <game.Bullet object at 0x0000026AAD4970B8>]
```

when i run i get this error `raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
 TypeError: Object of type Bullet is not JSON serializable`

i also tried to work with the json storage function from kivy but that is basicly also a json file so theres no difference. my first idea was to turn this list into a string and turn it back to a list when needed i asked that here '[how to turn a whole list into a string and a string back to a whole list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61942287/how-to-turn-a-whole-list-into-a-string-and-a-string-back-to-a-whole-list)' well the other opinion would be to save all this data from each widget all by myself but that would be super much work and a lot of code. so i hope you can help me with that.it dont need to be json if you have any way in saving this it help i tried the pickle module already but idk

here is a code example how you can get this kind of a list

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock




class widd(Widget):
    text = StringProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(widd, self).__init__(**kwargs)




gui = Builder.load_string("""

<widd>:
    pos: self.pos
    size_hint: None,None
    size: 30, 30
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,1,0,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos



FloatLayout:
    id: main
    Button:
        size_hint: .2, .2
        pos_hint: {'bottom': 1, 'right': 1}
        on_release:
            app.spawn()



""")
class Testapp(App):

    def build(self):
        return gui


    def on_start(self):
        self.widgets = []
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.move, 1)

    def move(self, dt):
        for wid in self.widgets:
            wid.x += 10
        print(self.widgets)

    def spawn(self):
        wid = widd()
        wid.pos= [10, 200]
        self.root.add_widget(wid)
        self.widgets.append(wid)



Testapp().run()
```

the list is `self.widgets`

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass the json encoder for your object type, basically the json serializer doesn't know which information to write to a json file.

Have a look at this article about [serialization](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/serialization-and-deserialization-of-python-objects-part-1--cms-26183).

here is a code example for that:

```
class CustomItemSerializer(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, CustomType): # this is the item class you want to serialize
            try:
                return {'__CustomItem__': o.property} 
# o.property can also be a dictionary, you add all relevant object properties here
            except TypeError:
                pass
            
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

you can then use the JSON dumps function with the "cls" argument:

```
dumps(item, indent=4, cls=CustomItemSerializer)
```

when decoding you write a decode function that creates an object with the properties that you've just serialized using the custom JSONEncoder.

```
    def decode_json_item(o):
    if '__CustomItem__' in o:
        item = KivyItem(o['__CustomItem__'])
        #when decoding the new object you use all the properties that you have already serialized to create your new object.
        return item
    
    return o
```

you can also change the structure of the output of the serializer it doesn't have to be this exact way, just try out different things and see which works best for you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is best to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. A code example can be very useful. Link-only responses may become invalid if the linked page changes.